# Best place to create global object in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I would like to implement [ConcurrentQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) object in my ASP.NET MVC app. The ConcurrentQueue object will be shared between sessions and should be created once. What is the best place to create ConcurrentQueue in ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any class you choose can hold an instance of it, however it would make most sense to couple it within a class that is responsible for whatever functionality the queue is used for.

For example a Cache class:

```
public class MyCache
{
     public static ConcurrentQueue Queue { get; private set; }

     static MyCache()
     {
          Queue = new ConcurrentQueue();
     }
}
```

This will initialize it the first time the MyCache class is used. If you want finer grain control, you could create an `Initialize` method that your Global.asax.cs file calls on app start.

Answer (score 3):

You could:

1. Create it in a static constructor, so it's created only when some code actually uses the type
2. Global.asax.
3. Use **WebActivator** - you won't pollute Global.asax file, and you can create the queue in different assembly.

Answer (score 2):

File `Global.asax.cs`, `protected void Application_Start()` method overload.

Another approach would be making a Singleton/static class.

Comment: Where I should declarate a ConcurrentQueue variable to access it later from code?

Comment: For `Global.asax.cs` approach - directly in Global.asax.cs, i.e. for example one line above Application_start do `public static ConcurrentQueue Queue { get; private set; }` and initialize it in Application_Start. For Singleton-static class please see @ChrisS answer